# How to project any folder changes to a new folder and leave original untouched?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, directory

In my program I am calling methods that do lots of changes to a content of a folder, including:

```
deleting files/folders,
changing files/folders,
adding files/folders,
adding/deleting symboliclinks/junctions.
```

That is no problem so far. But I came up with the idea of optionally projecting the final state of the folder (after all the operations are done) to another folder, so that the original folder remains untouched.

Just copying the folder before applying the operations is not appropriate, because the operations might delete large chunks of data, that would have to be unnecessarily copied beforehand. And so it came to my mind, that a professional programmer would certainly not approach it this way.

Ideally I would write something like this (pseudo code):

originalFolder.Delete(lots of files).Add(Some other stuff, maybe change some permissions etc).ProjectTo(newFolder)

Is there some kind of design pattern or other way I could achieve something like this? Maybe some virtual file system I can do stuff on before materializing it into a seperate folder?

I know how to write extension methods and I have already written lots of trivial ones, but I really need to be put on the right path on how to achieve something like this.

Comment: Sounds a bit unclear. You're saying you want to be able to mock up a change to a specific file in one folder, then actually make that change in another folder. What file would it chose to change in the other folder?

Comment: Do you wish to project your changes only or the final state of the original folder? Because if you only want the final state of the original folder it comes down to taking a copy of the original folder after all your operations are complete...

Comment: I want to assure that the original folder is never ever touched, so let's assume it is read only. Now I want to define all kinds of virtual changes to that folder (add/delete files/folders/links). And then I want to create a folder in another location that is an exact copy of the folder as IF it was modified in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to delay changes to the original folder until you are certain that you want to commit them, then a Unit of Work pattern might do the trick. Store all operations that are to be applied to the folder in a container, and then commit them sequentially.

This sounds a bit dangerous though, since changes to the original folder before changes are committed easily can mess things up. In that case you would have to implement some sort of concurrency check to be as certain as possible that all operations will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If the adding and deleting would be done through YOUR apis, then you can modify the list of files in memory without touching the physical files and when you are set do the changes with the copy on the final folder.

Of course that assumes that you don't need the files changed in any matter thus you won't need to read the new structure through the filesystem before committing, I mean that it would be totally within your application.

If this was on linux, I would have suggested another solution which is to use hard links and hard link the files to many folders and thus actually do whatever you want with the first folder without touching the second. I am not sure if NTFS supports that.

Comment: +1 - Yes this is what I would do too. To paraphrase AhHatem, build an object tree by recursing the original file structure, perform all the operations virtually on the in-memory tree, then copy only the files left over after any virtual delete operations.